Selenium with Appium: Location of an element does not change after being scrolled into view
I'm using Selenium with Appium in C# to run my automated tests. I have an element that is visible within the DOM, but is hidden behind a button (it is located in a scrollable table). I have successfully implemented a scroll function that scrolls and displays the element. When I try to click on the element, Selenium clicks on the original location of the element (which is behind a button). My test fails because of this. I noticed that the location of the element before and after the scroll is the same. How can I fix this and is there a way to adjust the location of the element after the scroll (once it becomes visible on the screen)?
Here is my code:
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Outil.Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
// Find the element by its locator before scrolling
By elementLocator = By.XPath("//android.widget.TextView[contains(@text, 'Tool')]");
IWebElement elementBeforeScroll = null;
try
{
    elementBeforeScroll = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(elementLocator));
}
catch (NoSuchElementException)
{
    // Handle NoSuchElementException if the element is not found before scrolling
    Console.WriteLine("Element not found before scrolling.");
}

// Perform the scroll action
int xValeur = 465;
int debutScroll = 1779;
int finScroll = 1395;

TouchAction touchAction = new TouchAction(Outil.Driver);
touchAction.Press(xValeur, debutScroll).Wait(1000).MoveTo(xValeur, finScroll).Release().Perform();
touchAction.Cancel();

Thread.Sleep(5000);

// Re-locate the element after scrolling
IWebElement elementAfterScroll = null;
try
{
    elementAfterScroll = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(elementLocator));  
}
catch (NoSuchElementException)
{
    // Handle NoSuchElementException if the element is not found after scrolling
    Console.WriteLine("Element not found after scrolling.");
}

// Click the element if it is found after scrolling
if (elementAfterScroll != null)
{
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    elementAfterScroll.Click();
}

Thanks in advance!

How do you check location?  There is location relative to the viewport and location relative to the window.  One of them will not change when scrolling.  Selenium should be clicking in the center of the element.  (the click() method also should scroll the element into view if needed)

@browsermator I checked the location by using the Location command. For example
Point locationElement = elementAfterScroll.Location . To check the location value in the x-axis, I then used locationElement.X and for the y-axis I used locationElement.Y. When I checked the location before and after scrolling, the values were the same.

I think that'll use getBoundingClientRect (relative to viewport) so it should change when scrolled.  Not real sure about droid, though...  to fix your issue though you shouldn't need to scroll.  The key will be in the exception.  It should tell you what element is overlapping, and that'll tell you why it is in front at the time you try to click.

@browsermator Thank you! I wasn't able to use getBoundingClientRect in my C# code, however, I was able to use the location of the element and then use TouchAction.Tap() to click on it.
